# Standard database maintenence jobs for SharePoint farm

Tags: wss-3.0, performance

I was wondering if there were any best practices to maintain performance of a SharePoint farm as sites and content are added. For example DBCC commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without repeating all stuff documented by Microsoft - go grab the Database Maintenance for WSS 3.0 whitepaper at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc307161(office.12).aspx